# How do i automatically assign textures to multiple meshes?

Tags: texturing, scripting

To keep this short,
i have 1,500 (estimate) materials that need texture assigning.
Since they're .DAE files, they dont import with textures.
Although, the materials have the same naming as their textures.
For example, in Blender, the material is named `AA_AA_example_AA000_A` and the texture file is the same.
Would there be a way to automatically assign all textures to the materials?
Image below shows my problem, the models import with no textures, but they have the same name as the texture it needs, which i thought could be solved if i just automate the process.
There are no image nodes.

[image: The model and the shading viewport.]

The last time i did things by hand, there were only 200 textures, which still was bad for my wrist
If anyone could please help me, i would greatly appreciate it! Thank you so much.
Please message me if you need more information so i could help you help me.
Apologies if this comes out the wrong way, i dont want my questions to come off in a negative way like last time. :(